# iPhone application cannot load images from an album

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have developed a small iPhone application in which a user can choose images from an image picker and that image will appear in a View.  When the user first selects an image I have saved the image name to a database and I save that image to a resource folder with that name.  When the main view appears I search for images from the resource folder and display that image in the main view.

When I run this application in the iPhone Simulator it successfully runs, but when I actually tried it for testing purposes on my iPhone I am not able to display images in the main view. Anyone have an idea what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 4):

**Hi shivang,**

I think you are saving the image to NSDocumentDirectory on a first click and trying to reload that.

1. while retriving the files from the NSDocumentDirectory you better
   first check it for the file type like jpg,png,mp3 then give the
   exact name to retrive that.
2. NSDocumentDirectory creates unique memory for every app and its
   limited,check for the size of the images u r saving.

better try this code

```
 for (NSString* fileName in [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myfilepath error:nil])
{
if ( [fileName rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location != NSNotFound  )

  {
      // Here fileName is used as a temporary variable to retrive image name
      // myfilepath is the path where u stored the images
  }
}
```